# Get the battery level of a bluetooth device on Raspberry PI 4

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, batterylevel, raspberry-pi4

For a personal project, I need in a web (HTMl, php and js) app to get the battery level of a device (phone, tablet) connected to the raspberry pi in bluetooth in a **Javascript file.**

My configuration:
 - Raspberry Pi 4 (4go) - Raspbian OS
 - smartphone: Android 10

Please help me. What should i do / install Change the OS ?

Comment: Hi there @BenjaminFB Welcome to SO, please tell us first what you have tried so far. we are not here to solve your school projects, you have to show us first that you tried hard before coming here.

Comment: I already tried that [Web Bluetooth / Battery Level Sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/battery-level.html) but it doesn't work. Maybe because I'm not in an HTTPS web app